# Bitwise Operation to check string is unique

Tags: java, string, bit-manipulation

This is the code to check if the input string is unique or not. What is being done at Line no. 11 : `check |=(1<<val)` and why is the check's binary form so?

```
public boolean checkUnique(String str)
 {
     int check=0;
     for(int i=0; i<str.length();i++)
     {
         int val = str.charAt(i)-'a';
         if((check & (1 << val)) >0)
         {
             return false;
         }
         check |= (1<<val);
         System.out.println("check "+Integer.toBinaryString(check));
     }
     return true;
 }
```

```
I/P : "asdfgh"
O/P () : 
0
check 1
18
check 1000000000000000001
3
check 1000000000000001001
5
check 1000000000000101001
6
check 1000000000001101001
7
check 1000000000011101001
```

Comment: Unique? A **single** string is always unique, I don't get it...

Comment: literally all of this and the below answers are massively overcomplicated, it can be much easier and much less error-prone : http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=xkehAziq

Comment: @MathiasBegert Sorry, unique characters of a string

Comment: @specializt Need to solve the problem without using any data structure

Comment: @KKR what is "data structure" supposed to mean? That doesnt make any sense - there are no structures in Java, only `Object`s and `primitives` - if your homework actually is about `primitives` ... well ... it is **unsolvable** because `String` is also an `Object` - it should've been `char[]` instead, then and only then would it be solvable.

Answer (score 1):

This code looks like is checking if every single character is unique in a string.

`int check=0;` initialise '`check`' with `0`;

`int val = str.charAt(i)-'a';` A ASCII char has max value of 127, minus 'a' which is 97, give a value between 0 - 30; [notice that, it seem this function can only check for character higher than or equal to 'a' (97), otherwise, val might be assigned with a negative value which does not make sense for the bitwise shift operation later on].

For the first iteration, "`if((check & (1 << val)) >0)`" will alway be false, 0 & with any int will be still 0;

Then the line "`check |= (1 < < val);`" left shift 0x01 with number of bits specified by 'val'. For instance if val = 3, (1 < < val) will be evaluated to 0x08. 0 bitwise-or with 0x08 will give 'check' a value of 0x08;

For the preceding iterations, a new 'val' is generated each time and the 'if' clause use bitwise-and to check if the 'val' already exists or not. If exists, return the function with false, otherwise, "record" the new 'val' in 'check' and continue with next iteration. When the loop finishes, return true.

Comment: Thanks for nicely explaining the logic but could you pls explain me what 0x08 is?

Comment: 0x08 is int 8, denoted in Hexadecimal format. or 0b00001000 is its binary format. You can find more information from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is, `check |= (1<<val)` means: "store a 1 at position val".

The line `(check & (1 << val)) >0` means: "is there a 1 at position val".

The line `val = str.charAt(i)-'a'` means: "assign each letter of the (lowercase) alphabet a unique val"

This will only work for alphabets at or below 31 letters in size, as that is the number of bits in an int whose value is not negative.

Answer (score 0):

`|` is the inclusive OR operator.  `|=` assigns the result of an inclusive OR operation to the indicated variable.  `<<` is the left shift bitwise operator.  It will shift binary data "to the left" by the indicated number of bits.

Line 11 is assigning the result of an inclusive OR operation, namely left shifting the number 1 left by `val` number of bits.

From what I see, the intention is to determine if the `check` variable has an associated bit already set via the AND operator `&` on line 7, and if so, `return false;` since that string does not contain only unique characters.

You may want to look into posts regarding use and function of bitwise operators and bit-shift operations.